# JPA Auto-Increment ID for each column value

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa

i am using JPA with EclipseLink and i am having a database table that looks like the following:

| DELIVERY_NR | COMPANY_NR | .... |
| --- | --- | --- |

while `DELIVERY_NR` and `COMPANY_NR` is the composed primary key.

### What I need to do

`DELIVERY_NR` needs to start at 1 and i need it to auto-increment it by 1 for each value of `COMPANY_NR`, so i would like to have the following result:

| DELIVERY_NR | COMPANY_NR | .... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1337 | ... |
| 2 | 1337 | ... |
| 1 | 5555 | ... |
| 2 | 5555 | ... |

How would i do this in a Java `Entity` ? At the moment im using `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` but this generates a sequence that just always counts up when a new entity is persisted, it does not take the value of `COMPANY_NR` into account.

Here is my entity at the moment:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DELIVERY")
@IdClass(value = Delivery.class)
public class Delivery{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "delivery_id_generator") // deliveryNr + companyNr
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "delivery_id_generator", sequenceName = "delivery_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_NR", nullable = false)
    private String deliveryNr;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NR", nullable = false)
    private String companyNr;

    // Some more non-id columns....
```

Comment: That's not possible with JPA. You would have to create your own SequenceGenerator

Comment: There is really no alternative? Maybe if i changed the database schema in some way?

Comment: No because a sequence is independent for each entity. You could create a database trigger that sets the ID and then use GenerationType.IDENTITY